# Importing S3FileUpload from react-s3 causes Unexpected Identifier error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am new to Javascript programming and have been learning React. The situtation is I am trying to upload an image to AWS S3 bucket. As the title says, when I try to import S3FileUpload from 'react-s3' SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier occurs

I have tried googling the problem but the only result I found with the same error was in another language which is unanswered: http://qaru.site/questions/17278232/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import-while-transpiling-reactjs-app-using-babel

```
import S3FileUpload from 'react-s3';
```

This is the log from terminal that appears:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Signature from "./Signature";
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\myrepo\node_modules\react-s3\index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I just went to the Github repo of the module and it appears that the name of the module has been changed to aws-S3 6 days ago. Working now!